# Stuff mulitple data elements in ORACLE 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to stuff several data elements into a column in Oracle 11g but only partially succeed. Below is two sample records.

```
IRS_Forms   Tax_Date        Tax_Id  Tax_Times
1040A       5/9/2011 4:51:00 AM BB11    2
1099B       5/9/2011 4:51:00 AM BB11    2
```

From here, I am able to stuff the IRS_Forms column as script below:

```
Select
Tax_Id,
Tax_Date,
LISTAGG(IRS_Forms,', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IRS_Forms) AS TAX_TYPES
from
 (
     IRS_Forms  Tax_Date        Tax_Id  Tax_Times
     1040A  5/9/2011 4:51:00 AM BB11    2
     1099B  5/9/2011 4:51:00 AM BB11    2
  )X
group by Tax_id, Tax_date
```

output result:

```
Tax_id  Tax_Date                Tax_TYPES
BB11    5/9/2011 4:51:00 AM     1040A, 1099B
```

How can I stuff additional data into the Tax_TYPES such as adding the counts within the () from Tax_Times column above? Here is my desired output:

```
Desired result:
Tax_id    Tax_Date            Tax_TYPES
BB11    5/9/2011 4:51:00 AM     1040A (2),1099B (2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
LISTAGG(IRS_Forms || ' (' || tax_times || ')',', ')  
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IRS_Forms) AS TAX_TYPES
```

Comment: @ Mr. Cave, Yes indeed. CONCATENATE is the keyword. Thanks so much, Sir!